# Makefile: why are commands for my target not executed?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to improve my understanding how `make` runs commands.
I have written this makefile:

```
TARGET=fmake
TARGET2=test_second
fmake: $(TARGET2).c foo.c\
    $(TARGET).c test.h
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c foo.c
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET2) $(TARGET2).c
foo.c:
    echo This is foo.c
clean:
    rm -f fmake test_second
CC=$(VAR2)
VAR2=gcc
```

And when running `make`, these shell commands displayed:

```
gcc -o fmake fmake.c foo.c
gcc -o test_second test_second.c
```

But I expect that there are three commands displayed (also target `foo.c`):

```
This is foo.c
gcc -o fmake fmake.c foo.c
gcc -o test_second test_second.c
```

Please, explain why this is so.

Comment: make starts on the first item ending with a :.  In this case it is fmake.  If you shift foo.c up then all it will do is the echo and nothing else.  If you want it to do the rest, foo.c has to have a dependency on fmake

Answer (score 4):

In your Makefile, `foo.c` has no dependencies. As long as that file exists, the corresponding actions will not be run.

It's the same thing that happens if you rerun `make`. The first thing it will try to build is `fmake`. But since all that target's dependencies already exist, and are older than the `fmake` file, nothing will be built. Same thing for `foo.c`, except that it has no dependencies (so it will never run the actions if the file exists).