# Two targets with no dependencies

Tags: bash, makefile

Consider the following makefile:

```
TARGET=fmake
TARGET2=test_second
fmake: $(TARGET2).c foo.c\
    $(TARGET).c test.h clean
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c foo.c
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET2) $(TARGET2).c
foo.c: 
    echo Some text
clean:
    rm -f fmake test_second
CC=$(VAR2)
VAR2=gcc
```

After the `make` bash command the following  display

```
rm -f fmake test_second
gcc -o fmake fmake.c foo.c
gcc -o test_second test_second.c
```

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931526/how-does-make-file-parse/20931575?noredirect=1#comment31430815_20931575) foo.c doesn't processed because there is no dependencies for this target. But both `foo.c` and `clean` have no dependencies, but clean is `processed`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a file called `foo.c` exists, whereas no file called `clean` exists.  So Make thinks that one needs to be made.  Note that `clean` should really be declared as a [*phony target*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets).

Comment: As I understood your answer first `make` tools looking for dependencies that declared in a considered target and if the dependencies exists then make starting to process one of them. If there is no rule for a specific dependency then make starting to update file with dependencie's name. If there is no dependencies in our target, then `make` looking for the file which name is a target name. If file not found then this rule is processing. Is my understanding correctl? But what with `default goal`? Does default goal processing always?

Comment: @Dmitrii: Put simply, Make only runs the rule for a target if either it doesn't exist (and isn't phony), or is "older" than its dependencies.  This rule applies to *all* targets, including top-level goals.